# How can I use GET method with an href to the same page?

Tags: php, html

Here's what I have:

```
<nav>
    <ul id="alphabet" class="pagination">
        <li><a href="?letter=A">A</a></li>
        <!-- B, C, D and so on... -->
    </ul>
</nav>
<?php
    if ($_GET["letter"]) {
        var_dump($_GET["letter"]);
    }
?>
```

When I click A, Instead of "var_dumping" A, it just goes to another page.

EDIT, I've replaced parse_url($url) with $_GET["letter"].

Comment: and the "other" page being named what? use `isset()` also.

Comment: and where is `$url` defined? have you read the manual on `parse_url()`?

Comment: worked fine for me `string(1) "A"` using `?param` should be using the same filename it was called from. Something else is causing your page to redirect to another page. *unable to reproduce*.

Comment: His answer did not work. By this "new page" I mean the **same** page, with the parameters passed via GET. I want to access them in order to alter the contents of the same page.

Comment: A guess: You want to use Ajax if you're going to "alter" anything on the same page and not be moved away from it.

Comment: Not necessarily. Is not a page reload the same thing as "to be moved away"? With the link, I want to reload the same page with the passed parameter.

Comment: "new page" means "new file". "Page reload" means "reload the same page". Sorry, but you'll need to take it up with the answer given to you below. There's nothing else I can say/do that will be of any further help. Wish I could, but I can't; given that I don't know what you're trying to achieve here, because your question is unclear. I sincerely wish you well, *cheers*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<nav>
    <ul id="alphabet" class="pagination">
        <li><a href="<?php echo( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);?>?letter=A">A</a></li>
        <!-- B, C, D and so on... -->
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This should do the trick.
You cannot add anything to get without reloading page